# Constants in terms of ideal: "stdio:4:11:(3): error: can't promote number to ring" in Macaulay2

Tags: runtime-error, macaulay2

I am trying to demonstrate Handelman's theorem and the example 1 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868615/handelmans-theorem-on-nonnegative-polynomial-in-compact-polytope) with Macaulay2. I cannot understand the error in defining the ideal for the polytope restricted by the intervals.

```
R=QQ[x1,x2,x3,MonomialOrder=>Lex];
I=ideal(x1-0.2,-x1+0.5,x2,-x2+1,x3-1,-x3+1)

stdio:2:11:(3): error: can't promote number to ring
```

and what is the error for? How should I define the constants?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Macaulay2 only accepts the computation for polynomial ring with `RR` not `QQ`:

```
i1 : R=RR[x1,x2,x3,MonomialOrder=>Lex]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : I=ideal(x1-0.2,-x1+0.5,x2,-x2+1,x3-1,-x3+1)

o2 = ideal (x1 - .2, - x1 + .5, x2, - x2 + 1, x3 - 1, - x3 + 1)

o2 : Ideal of R
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because M2 views decimals as real numbers as opposed to rationals:

> i1 : .2
>
> o1 = .2
>
> o1 : RR (of precision 53)

So .2 isn't in your base ring.
Use fraction notation (as opposed to decimal notation) to input your ideal and you'll be in business.

> i2 : R=QQ[x1,x2,x3, MonomialOrder => Lex];
>
> i3 : I=ideal(x1-1/5,-x1+1/2,x2,-x2+1,x3-1,-x3+1)
>
> o3 = ideal (x1 - 1/5, - x1 + 1/2, x2, - x2 + 1, x3 - 1, - x3 + 1)
>
> o3 : Ideal of R